# Notepad++ find value in one column but change a different column

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have an "old school" import file.  First character contains a 1, 2, or 3 to indicate type of line.  Second character through 7th character has a vendor number.  I wish to find a 1 in the first character and then a variable vendor in positions 2 through 7.  Then for records that meet that criteria change the contents to a variable in positions 92 through 99 regardless of the contents of positions 92 through 99.

My file:

```
1894   004dzxjvugin       PCard11012019                 10031910031912611        0
```

Looking for a 1 in character postion 1 then supplying 894 as the variable vendor to match beginning in character position 2.  Then I wish to update this record to contain the supplied variable `V9952164911/12/19` beginning in position 92.

It seems the syntax of Notepad++ should do the job but I am inexperienced using it for this purpose.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59772808/edit) and add expected result.

Comment: The line given as example is 90 character long, is it a wrong copy/paste from the original file or are data missing? The supplied variable `V9952164911/12/19` is longer than the 7 characters available between position 92 to 99. Please, clarify your needs.

Comment: You are correct.  Sorry for the confusion.  The part that is the going in 92 through 99 starts with the 99 and is 99521649.  Then a date will go in 100 through 107 which in my prior example is 11/12/99.  The V will be in position 91 and will have the V there at the point I am trying to make the change. This will potentially have as many as 2000 records that will need to be changed.  That is why I am looking for an automated type of Find/Replace functionality.

Comment: Begin:1894   004dzxjvugin       PCard11012019                 10031910031912611        0        V                                                                                            
Changed:1894   004dzxjvugin       PCard11012019                 10031910031912611        0        V9952164911/12/19                                        
 but only for records that contain 1 in character position 1 and 894 in character positions 2 through 4

Comment: Have a try with Find: `^1894.{86}\K` and Replace: `V9952164911/12/19`. Does it work for you?

Comment: That worked perfectly.  If you do not mind explaining each element of the string that was used in the Find.  I understand 1894 and 86 and the replace string.  But what exactly do ^, the parenthesis, . (the period) and \K mean?

Comment: This worked.  It seems to insert the characters in the replace.  That works for me in this situation but is there a way to instruct it to overlay the characters that are there with the replace string.  If something is already in those character positions they get moved to the right and retained instead of replacing.

Comment: I've posted an answer that works, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^1894.{86}\K.{17}`
- Replace with: `V9952164911/12/19`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  1894      # literally 1894
  .{86}     # exactly 86 any characters but newline
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  .{17}     # 17 characters
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  I appreciate you taking the time to help.  I am a new user but I believe I have accepted your answer.